# Is it possible for a group to be a finite union of subgroups of infinite index?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Just restating the title: Does there exist a group $G$ and subgroups $H_1, \ldots, H_k$ so that $[G:H_i]$ is infinite for each $i = 1, 2, \ldots, k$, and $G = H_1 \cup \cdots \cup H_k$?

If $G$ is a vector space over an infinite field $F$ and the $H_i$ are subspaces, then it is a standard exercise to show that this is impossible. What I'm asking is whether or not it is still impossible in this more general setting.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's not trivial, but the answer is no. See this [MathOverflow question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/217674/can-a-group-be-a-union-of-finitely-many-subgroups-of-infinite-index?lq=1).

In fact, a more general result of B.H. Neumann implies that a group can't be the union of finitely many cosets of infinite index subgroups. More precisely, it states that if a group is the union of $n$ cosets of subgroups, then at least one of the subgroups must have index at most $n$.